# How to upload and run a script with laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to write a php script (say A) which run an uploaded typescript (say B) which was uploaded with a CRUD (input file form).

I know how to upload files like images, and I guess that uploading a ts script which is a text file is not very different, but I have no idea how am I supposed to run this new script on a page...

Anyone can help ?

Comment: You'd need to to compile the .ts file to JavaScript after the upload. This is a fairly complex undertaking.

Comment: Oh ok, so let's say that i want to run a simple Js script.
I successed to store a very simple js script (which display "hello world") in my "storage" folder, but I don't know how to use it in my page...